# How can I see if a method is a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, introspection

Is it possible to inspect a function/method to see whether it can be used as a decorator? In that it follows the usual way decorators wrap other functions and return a callable? Specifically, I'm looking to validate 3rd party code.

Comment: Do you mean *can be used as a decorator* or *is used as a decorator somewhere*? While the first could prove very hard, if not impossible to solve generally, the second might actually be doable.

Comment: or are you asking if the function has been decorated?

Comment: @NiklasB. sorry - clarified the question.

Comment: @unpluggd: Seeing that this is an impossible task as it stands, maybe we can help you better if you tell us why you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By applying a suspected decorator, catching exceptions, and then testing whether the result contains a `__call__` method, you could produce a guess as to whether a given callable is a decorator or not.  But it will be only a guess, not a guarantee.

Beyond that, I do not believe what you want will be possible in general, due to the dynamically typed nature of the Python language and to the special treatment of built-in functions in the CPython interpreter.  It is not possible to programmatically tell whether a callable will accept another callable as an argument, or what type its return value will have.  Also, in CPython, for functions implemented in C, you cannot even inspect a callable to see how many arguments it accepts.

The word "decorator" can be taken to mean different things.  One way to define it is, a decorator is any callable that accepts a single (callable) argument and returns a callable.

Note that I have not even used the word "function" in this definition; it would actually be incorrect to do so.  Indeed, some commonly used decorators have strange properties:

- The built-in `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators return descriptor objects, not functions.
- Since language version 2.6 you can decorate classes, not just functions and methods.
- Any class containing an `__init__(self, somecallable)` method and a `__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)` method can be used as a decorator.

Comment: Thanks - your statement that a decorator can be "[a] callable that accepts a single callable argument and returns a callable" would be the basis for my test and should be enough for validation as this is how they should be created in the 3rd-party code. However, judging by the complexity, I'm just going to try and provide some nice error messages instead. :D

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no standardized decorator in Python, there's no real way of telling if a function is a decorator unless you know something about the decorator you're looking for.

If the decorator is under your control, you can add a mark to indicate it's a decorated function. Otherwise there is no real unified way of doing this. Take this example for instance:

```
def decorator(func):
    return g

@decorator
def f()
    pass

def g():
    pass
```

In the above example, in run-time, f and g will be identical, and there is no way of telling the two apart.

Answer (score 2):

Any callable with the right number of arguments can be used as a decorator. Remember that

```
@foo
def bar(...):
```

is *exactly* the same as

```
def bar(...):
   ...
bar = foo(bar)
```

Naturally, since `foo` could return *anything*, you have no way of checking whether a function has been decorated or not. Although `foo` could be nice and leave a mark, it has no obligation to do so.

---

If you are given some Python code and you want to find all the things that are decorators, you can do so by parsing the code into an abstract syntax tree then walking the tree looking for decorated functions. Here's an example, storing the `.id`s of the decorators. Obviously, you could store the `ast`objects if you wanted to.

```
>>> class DecoratorFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super(DecoratorFinder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         self.decorators = set()
...     
...     def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
...         self.decorators.update(dec.id for dec in node.decorator_list)
...         self.generic_visit(node)
... 
>>> finder = DecoratorFinder()
>>> x = ast.parse("""
... @dec
... def foo():
...     pass
... """)
>>> finder.visit(x)
>>> finder.decorators
set(['dec'])
```

Comment: Actually only callables are possible which take at least one positional argument...

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. May be instead of checking if `f` is a decorator, you should think why you need to check that?

If you are expecting some specific decorator, you can directly check that, if you want some specific behavior/methods/attributes you can check that

If you want to check if some callable `f` can be used as decorator, you can test the decorator behavior by passing some dummy function, but in general it may not work or have different behavior for different inputs.

Here is a such naive check:

```
def decorator1(func):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "before"
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "after"

    return _wrapper

def dummy_func(): pass

out_func = decorator1(dummy_func)

if callable(out_func) and dummy_func != out_func:
    print "aha decorated!"
```

Comment: `you can check that directly by passing some dummy function`?? Not really... you can't tell _what_ it will do with its argument!

Comment: @katrielalex yes that why general answer is No, but if you know what decorator is supposed to do, you can possibly check the behavior by using it

Answer (score 0):

I've never done anything like this, but in general python relies on "duck-typing" in situations like this. So you could just try to decorate a dummy function and see if a callable is returned.